# How to catch Errors thrown in onData Methods of stream.listen

Tags: dart, error-handling, stream

I'm building an Event driven application with Dart.

Therefor I have one central stream where all Events are put on.

```
class EventManager {
  final StreamController<Event> _dataStreamController =
      StreamController<Event>.broadcast();

  Stream get stream => _dataStreamController.stream;

  void addEvent(event) {
    _dataStreamController.sink.add(event);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to catch all Errors that are thrown during the onData Method of all the listens on my central Stream in one place.

Sample of a listen and its onData Method(handleMyEvent):

```
eventManager.stream
        .where((event) => event is MyEvent)
        .listen(handleMyEvent);

 void handleMyEvent(event) {
    //handles MyEvent
    //might throw an Error
    throw Errror();
 }
```

Or would every onData Method(handleMyEvent) need it's own try catch block like this:

```
 void handleMyEvent(event) {
    try{
      //handles MyEvent
      //might throw an Error
    } catch (generalError) {
      //handle Error
    }
 }
```

because it's not possible to catch it in a central place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `onData` handler throws, it becomes an *uncaught asynchronous error*. There is no surrounding context to catch that error, and nowhere to forward it to.

The only way to catch those errors is to introduce an uncaught error handler in the zone where the `onData` handler is run.
Example:

```dart
runZonedGuarded(() {
  stream.listen((event) {
    mayThrow(event);
  });
}, (e, s) {
  log(e, s); // or whatever.
});
```

If you use `stream.forEach(onDataHandler)` instead, then the handler throwing will terminate the `forEach` and the error will be reported in the returned future.
I recommend *always* using `forEach` over `listen` unless you need access to the stream subscription returned by `listen`, or need to handle error events instead of just stopping at the first one.

Comment: since I don't want to stop on first Error forEach isn't really an option for me

Comment: What would you consider better practice using one Zone around my whole asynchronous stuff in the main programm or either seperate zones for each listen or a try catch in every onData handler (having a zone around each listen or try catch in every onData handler seem to be equal solutions)

Comment: I'd say that's up to you. I'd probably use the `try`/`catch` to handle the error locally, and avoid setting up extra zones. It's easier and just as good. On the other hand, if you want to treat all the errors the same way, a single error-handling zone might be easier.